# Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

i am new in android studio
i create my first project and got this rendering error

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:

- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)[enter link description here](http://s32.postimg.org/580sa08mt/Untitlednew.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your XML file ?

Also did you add the this to the dependencies in the build gradle file ?

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```